# jQuery - Get nearest element with class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have very mess html code like this and i cant influence the structure.

```
<div class="head">
  <p class="any">something 1</p>
</div>
<input type="text" class="mand" value="1">

<div class="head">
  <p class="any-else">something 2</p>
</div>
<div class="foo">    
  <input type="text" class="mand" value="2">
</div>

<div class="head">
  <p class="any">something 3</p>
</div>
<div class="foo">    
  <div class="another-needless-div">      
    <input type="text" class="mand" value="3">
  </div>
</div>
```

I need for every input with class "mand" the next above text from p in the head-div.
For example: For the input field with value"3", I need the p text "something 3".

```
$(".mand").each(function(){
  console.log( $(this).prev(.head).find('p').text() ); // not working
});
```

How can i get this content? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this, this will loop through each parent until it has a prev element with the class `head`

```
function parent(obj) {
  if ($(obj).prev(".head").length) {
    return $(obj).prev(".head").find("p").text()
  } else {
    return parent($(obj).parent())
  }
}

$.each($('.mand'), function() {
  console.log(parent($(this)));
})
```

```js
function parent(obj) {
  if ($(obj).prev(".head").length) {
    return $(obj).prev(".head").find("p").text()
  } else {
    return parent($(obj).parent())
  }
}

$.each($('.mand'), function() {
  console.log(parent($(this)));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="head">
  <p class="any">something 1</p>
</div>
<input type="text" class="mand" value="1">

<div class="head">
  <p class="any-else">something 2</p>
</div>
<div class="foo">
  <input type="text" class="mand" value="2">
</div>

<div class="head">
  <p class="any">something 3</p>
</div>
<div class="foo">
  <div class="another-needless-div">
    <input type="text" class="mand" value="3">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really can't fix your code, and it will always be like that (which, of course we both now it can be improved), you can code it like this:

```
$.each($('.mand'), function(){
    console.log($(this).parent().siblings().children('p').text());
})
```

Answer (score 0):

please try this

```
console.log( $(this).prev('.head').find('p').text() );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you could be able to have "**.foo**" div parent for **every** "**.mand**", it would look like this.

```
$(".mand").each(function(){
  console.log( $(this).closest('.foo').prev('.head').find('p').text() ); 
});
```

it would work for this html

```
<div class="head">
  <p class="any-else">something 2</p>
</div>
<div class="foo">    
  <input type="text" class="mand" value="2">
</div>

<div class="head">
  <p class="any">something 3</p>
</div>
<div class="foo">    
  <div class="another-needless-div">      
    <input type="text" class="mand" value="3">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, first you need to structure your html codes as follows (Your original codes use different structure for each input, which makes hard for the selector to find the correct contents in the p tag. Also, it is a good practice to name the similar components with the same class name.):

```
<div class="head">
  <p class="any">something 1</p>
</div>
<div class="foo"> 
  <input type="text" class="mand" value="1">
<div>

<div class="head">
  <p class="any">something 2</p>
</div>
<div class="foo">    
  <input type="text" class="mand" value="2">
</div>

<div class="head">
  <p class="any">something 3</p>
</div>
<div class="foo">         
   <input type="text" class="mand" value="3">
</div>
```

Then, you could simply use the following jQuery codes to get the contents:

```
$(".mand").each(function(){
    console.log($(this).parent().prev().children(".any").text());
});
```

Hope this could help!